# slideToggle sliding up and down when you click on the links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im having a little issue with the following code, i am wanting it to open if you click on a link, and if you click another any that are open will close before the new one opens.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="link_1" class="expandCourse">test link 1</a>
<div class="link_1" style="display:none;">content here</div>

<a href="#" id ="link_2" class="expandCourse">test link 2</a>
<div class="link_2" style="display:none;">content here</div>

<a href="#" id="link_3" class="expandCourse">test link 3</a>
<div class="link_3" style="display:none;">content here</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.expandCourse').on('click',function() {
    var courseID = $(this).attr('ID');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("."+courseID).slideToggle('slow', function() {
        if ($('.expandCourse').hasClass('active')){
            $("."+courseID).slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $("."+courseID).slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znFmc/18/

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.expandCourse').on('click',function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) { 
        $('.expandCourse').removeClass('active')
        var courseID = $(this).attr('ID');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.content').slideUp('slow', function() {
            $("."+courseID).slideDown('slow');
        });
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/znFmc/22/)

Comment: Thanks for helping, and opens now but if 1 is open and you click another i need the other to close so only 1 can be open at anyone time, how would i amend it for that? thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, what would i change this part to? as it seems to make the who size div scroll up and not the actual item div $('div').not("."+courseID).slideUp('slow', function() {

Comment: You can see what i mean here:http://jsfiddle.net/znFmc/21/ if i place a div around all of it

Comment: Works great thanks! Sorry to be a pain as i know your being very helpful what would i change / add so it allows you to close the same one already open as if i open one and click link on same one it stays open and does not close. Promise that will be the last part and thanks again!

Comment: Its ok i have managed to work that out, thanks for your help!